# asp.net core overwrite default authentication policy

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I set up the authorization with one default and one named policy like this

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        AuthorizationPolicyBuilder defaultPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        defaultPolicyBuilder = defaultPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        options.DefaultPolicy = defaultPolicyBuilder.Build();

        options.AddPolicy("CertOnly", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        });
    });
```

basically, the default scheme will accept jwt, cookie, and cert whereas cert only should only accept the cert

It works perfectly fine if I only have one `[Authorize]` tag defined

However, it stopped working when I apply the `[Authorize]` tag on the controller level and want to overwrite it on the action to be `[Authorize(Policy = "CertOnly")]`

Looks like it is doing an OR operation when multiple Authorize attributes are defined since I can now call the action using a valid Jwt. If I remove the `[Authorize]` on the controller then I can only call it using a valid cert.

How can I make it to be an AND operation or simply overwrite the default policy?

Comment: I suggest that you overwrite the default policy. It could involve multiple levels of certification.

Comment: @Karney. the question is how? How do I use default and the named policy at the same time?

Comment: Sorry for so long time, The certificate authentication is for each request by default, please see the official website [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0#can-i-configure-my-app-to-require-a-certificate-only-on-certain-paths). If the current request is only for certificate authentication. You can write middleware to determine the schema of the current request, and reject other authentication schemas based on the requested path. You can refer to official code(authentication middleware).

Comment: @Karney. thats the last assort that i am trying to avoid. The authentication scheme provides the exact thing i need and i want to be able to utilize that since its built in and requires no custom code

Comment: The another way is to customalize a middleware to  get the schema from `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider`  and the route path. Then block authentication schemes other than the current one.

Comment: @Karney. no need to go that far. I can simply change the policy to `policy.RequireAssertion(context => context.User.Identities.Any(x => x.AuthenticationType == CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));` and it will work. however multiple Authorize attribute should be AND operation and I am wondering why its not working here.